# QGIS creating _attachments.zip files in project directory

Tags: qgis

The question says it all. I've noticed that when I open a project, edit something and then close the project a new zip file is created with the project name appended by "_attachments.zip". I updated to 3.26.3 a few days ago and I think this behavior started then. The zip file contains 1 or 2 files with a random set of characters followed by "_styles.db". It doesn't seem to cause any harm but I don't imagine it's doing any good either...

Deleting the file doesn't seem to do anything.

Can anyone comment on whether this is a bug or a feature? I don't see anything in the changelog.

Comment: Drive-by downvotes really don't accomplish anything. If it's a stupid question tell me why.

Comment: _Not_ a stupid question. [Others](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/444381/safely-rename-a-qgis-project) (ahem) want to know, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called the QGD file, and is only visible because the project is saved as .QGS.  When saved as .QGZ, the QGD and .QGS files are compressed together (yes, the .QGZ is a zip folder)

This is auxiliary project data stored in a sqlite database.  If you need to apply custom overrides to labels, QGIS makes it easier going by storing and maintaining this info in this file.

Refer below link for more details on auxiliary data:
https://oslandia.com/en/2017/10/17/auxiliary-storage-support-in-qgis-3/

Comment: How do I stop QGIS from generating this files?

Comment: Simply save as *.qgz instead of *.qgs file.
From menu toolbar, 'Project', 'Save As', browse to location and select Save as type: *.qgz