# Safely rename a QGIS project

Tags: qgis, qgs, rename

How do you rename a project without breaking it?

I used the Rename option from the Manage option of the context-sensitive menu in the Browser to rename my `project1`. This seems to work. However, I noticed a `project1_attachments.zip` file alongside `project1`. This `.zip` file seems unchanged by the Rename. I am concerned that when I copy this project to a new location, something will break, especially if I have multiple projects in a directory (maybe I should avoid that).

Should I rename the `.zip` file, too? Will that break the project? Judging from the Browser view (see image), I am pretty sure the `.zip` was created by QGIS—I can't think of any other program on this system that would create something like it.

I need to rename the project because I want to move it to a new location where a name of  "project1" will not be specific enough to identify it.

I don't mind if a project is stored in two files (I actually like that `.gqs` is at least somewhat human readable—XML?), I just need to know how to manage properly.

I am using `QGIS 3.26.3-Buenos Aires`.

My options say to default to QGZ (see image). See also [General Settings](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#general-settings).

[image: An "attachments.zip" seems to be associated with my project, judging by the file name.]

[image: Options address QGZ format]

Comment: Why don't you just change the file name?

Comment: @Erik as stated: "I am concerned that... something will break."

Comment: What's in that zip file? Where did it come from? I've been using QGIS for years and never seen anything like that. Did a plugin create it?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/441331/qgis-creating-attachments-zip-files-in-project-directory

Comment: What should break when you rename the project file?

Comment: @Spacedman I edited the post in attempt to answer "What's in that zip... Where did it come from..."

Comment: Why not just save the project as a new one with the new name, in the new location, or if you can't do that directly save it to a different location and move that.

Comment: @John RE "save... as... new name" I was thinking of writing that as an answer, myself, in hopes that someone would come along and leapfrog it with a better answer. I would prefer a true rename, though, if that is possible---and that's the question I am asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think yes, you probably should rename the attachments file also.

However, there's a comment from Nyall Dawson on this issue which seems to imply that these attachment files are only present when you save as `.qgs`, and not if you save as the newer `.qgz` format:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/48857

when the attachments are embedded in the `.qgz` file.

I'd recommend saving as `.qgz`, and then the attachments file shouldn't re-appear, and you can rename the `.qgz` to anything.

If you are already working happily with `.qgz` then the attachments file must be a hangover from when maybe you were working on a `.qgs` in the past and can probably be deleted.

Comment: Tried saving new projects several ways: `Save`, `Save As`, each time specifying the QGZ format, either placing a `.qgz` suffix at the end of the name or not. I still get two files, e.g. a `project.qgz` and a `project.qgz_attachments.zip`.

Comment: Are you sure you are saving things with the extension correctly, and not just creating a file called `project.qgz.qgs`? Windows can be set to hide extensions and this can lead to weird things happening.

Comment: Re "...hide extensions..." I'm not using Windows (good suggestion, though). I believe my distro's `ls` command is reporting the full file names: they do not have the double extension.

Comment: Hmmm. I think the "should I rename it" question is answered ("yes") but not the "where are these attachment files coming from" question which is a different thing altogether! If it bothers you, make a new Q or ask on the QGIS github issues.

Comment: Well, "just renaming" the `.qgs` seems to work. If I rename, the `.qgs`, move it, and reopen it, I don't notice and significant difference in the content (except the broken links because the relative paths to external files are no longer valid). The `_attachments.zip` seems not to be required, and is regenerated when I save the `.qgs`, if I don't move the `.zip` along with the `.qgs`. And, yes, what the `.zip` file is is another question.