# What's in (project-name)_attachments.zip

Tags: qgis, file-formats, qgs

In addition to a project file, `project-name.qgs`, QGIS is saving `project-name_attachments.zip`. Deleting the `.zip` file seems not to have a significant effect. A new one gets created when I save the project again.

1. What's in the `_attachments.zip` and
2. Can it be deleted without losing essential information about the project?

### See Also

[QGIS File Formats](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/appendices/qgis_file_formats.html?highlight=qgs#)

### Related Question

[a bug or a feature?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/441331/qgis-creating-attachments-zip-files-in-project-directory)

Comment: I've also spotted this recently and would like to know the purpose of it... Appears to contain within a '.db' file which I can't read in a text editor.